# IPFW denies ssl connections

Tags: ssl, freebsd, ipv6, ipfw

I'm having an issues loading https websites (google, facebook, amazon) through my PHP scripts using functions like `fsockopen`, `file_get_contents`. Operation is being timed out. So I started looking through my system settings and noticed that when ipfw service is being stopped, it works like a charm.

So this is an issue definately related to my IPFW configuration. I have enabled logging and this pops out in the log file while trying to execute the PHP script:

```
ipfw: 1000 Deny ICMPv6:1.3 [2001:...:...:...::] [2001:...:2:...::] in via em0
ipfw: 1000 Deny ICMPv6:131.0 [...::...:...:...:...] [...::1:...:0] in via em0
ipfw: 1000 Deny ICMPv6:136.0 [2001:...:...:...:ff:ff:ff:ff] [...:...:2:...::] in via em0
```

Looks like an issue with the IPv6, though, I do `allow all` keep state-kind connections in my ipfw file.

Here is the configuration I'm currently using:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

IPF="/sbin/ipfw -q add"

/sbin/ipfw -q -f flush

$IPF 10 allow all from any to any via lo0
$IPF 11 deny all from any to 127.0.0.0/8
$IPF 12 deny all from 127.0.0.0/8 to any
$IPF 13 deny tcp from any to any frag

$IPF 250 check-state
$IPF 260 allow tcp from any to any established
$IPF 270 allow all from any to any out keep-state
$IPF 280 allow icmp from any to any

$IPF 290 allow log tcp from 127.0.0.1/32 to 127.0.0.1/32 3306 in

$IPF 350 allow udp from any to any 53 in
$IPF 351 allow tcp from any to any 53 out
$IPF 352 allow tcp from any to any 80 in
$IPF 353 allow tcp from any to any 80 out
$IPF 361 allow tcp from any to any 443 in
$IPF 362 allow tcp from any to any 443 out
$IPF 363 allow tcp from any to any 22 in
$IPF 364 allow tcp from any to any 22 out

$IPF 1000 deny log all from any to any
```

Also: I started having this problem after upgrading to FreeBSD 10.3 (9.2 earlier).

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not use IPv6, but I notice from `/etc/rc.firewall` and `/etc/protocols` that ICMP has a different symbolic name for IPv6 which is `ipv6-icmp`. If you need to pass IPv6 ICMP packets, you may want to add a new rule:

```
allow ipv6-icmp ...
```

I do not understand your existing rules, and you may have separated `in` and `out` rules for diagnostics purposes, but:

```
allow tcp from any to any xxx in
allow tcp from any to any xxx out
```

Is similar (if not equivalent) to:

```
allow tcp from any to any xxx
```

Also, all of your `out` rules are pre-empted by rule 270 anyway.

If your server needs to use name service, you are missing a rule to allow responses from the remote DNS server over UDP:

```
allow udp from any 53 to any
```

Comment: `icmp6` works as well. Also thanks for catching the 270 rule.